# Angular 2+ : How to parse json data in Typescript component in Angular

Tags: json, angular, typescript, components, angular5

My json data:

```
{
"Temp": [
    {
        "dt": 1485717216,
        "temp":30,
        "time":"05:17:55 PM"
    }
]
}
```

I can parse above json -

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._weather.dailyForecast()
      .subscribe(mdata => {

        let temp1 = mdata['Temp'].map(mdata => mdata.temp)
        let time = mdata['Temp'].map(mdata => mdata.time)
    }
}
```

**But I'm facing problem while parsing below json data-**

```
{
        "temp":30,
        "time":"05:17:55 PM"
}
```

Can any one tell me how to parse json data?

Update code:
Service code

```
export class WeatherService {

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

  dailyForecast() {
    return this._http.get("----url----")
      .map(result => result);
  }
}
```

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: are you using `HttpClient` module?

Comment: are you using http or httpclient to retrieve data from the  server? I can help you more, if you can post the code in the Angular service

Comment: i want to plot a dynamic graph - temp vs time so i'm getting data in above format but geting confusion in parsing the same

Comment: in service, i'm using HttpClient only

Comment: then you don't have to use map. You can directly subscribed to the observable

Comment: @EasiTest  [Type checking responses](https://blog.angularindepth.com/the-new-angular-httpclient-api-9e5c85fe3361)

Comment: @RukshanDangalla That's the array map function, not the observable map function

Comment: see updated code..

Comment: @user184994 He use map in the service as well.

Comment: help me yaar i'm new to angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think OP's facing an issue while getting response as object rather than an Array.

You need to handle that in case with custom code and add for a check as necessary,

also you need to make **mdata** to type of **`any`** since it varies.

Inside your subscribe,

```
  .subscribe((mdata :any) => {
        if(mdata['Temp']){
        let temp1 = mdata['Temp'].map(mdata => mdata.temp)
        let time = mdata['Temp'].map(mdata => mdata.time)
        }
        else
        {
        let temp1 = mdata.temp;
        let time = mdata.time;
        }
    }
```

Comment: mdata.temp is not recognizing

Comment: while compiling?

Comment: No, temp is doesn't exist on type 'object'